# Calculation of silver nanoparticle size using Mie Theory

Tags: absorption

I have synthesized silver nano-particles and I wish to determine the approximate particle size using the wavelength that was most absorbed according to its absorption spectrum.

I find out that Mie theory provides a good approximation for this, (Eq 4 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yuriy_Gnatenko2/post/Can_anyone_explain_how_to_calculate_particle_size_from_Uv-Vis_spectra/attachment/59d6322ac49f478072ea168b/AS:273630724853779@1442250056479/download/Ag_nanoparticle+size.pdf)). However, I am clueless as to how to use the equation. In other words, how should I use the $\lambda_{max}$ obtained through the experiment in the provided equation?

Comment: Wait isn't Equation 4 $\gamma (R) = \gamma _0 + (Av_f)/R$? Where's the $λ_{max}$?

Comment: Yes, it is.  However, the first answer on the link suggests to use it. https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anyone_explain_how_to_calculate_particle_size_from_Uv-Vis_spectra

Comment: Oh, the application took pretty long to load. So I didn't see that at first! Thanks!

Comment: So any insights on my problem?

Comment: Not yet, but I’ll work on this in math class. Middle school is so easy :)

Comment: Just wondering, do you work in a lab? Because https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43030181#43030181

Comment: Yes, I do work in a lab and I find it better to ask the question over here, then to reach those experts in the lab (which I think is allowed, since I have explained the question clearly and provided the research that I have done).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73593/discussion-between-javascriptcoder-and-mathnoob123).

Answer (score 1):

### Plug it in to the math equation

Ok, so we have this equation: $γ(R)=γ_0+(Av_f)/R$

First, we substitute the values into the equation that we know.
$γ(R) = (5\cdot10^{12}) + (3/4\cdot1.39\cdot10^6)/R$. Simplified, this is:
$γ(R) = (5\cdot10^{12}) + (1.0425 \cdot 10^6)/R$

$γ(R)$ can be measured in your experiment. Then we can solve your equation for $R...$
$\large{R = \fbox{$\frac{1.0425 \cdot 10^6}{γ(R) - 5\cdot10^{12}}$}}$

Plug in your value of $γ(R)$, and you're there!*

> *In other words, how should I use the λmax obtained through the experiment in the provided equation?
>
> The equation only mentions $\gamma (R)$, I don't know how to help you there**

---

> **[Zhe](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/35555/zhe): @JavaScriptCoder For these types of questions, the first thing to ask is "do you work in a lab?"
> If not, why are you doing experiments outside of a lab, and if so, why is it that no one in your lab has any expertise on this?

Comment: Here you go. I don't know what $λ_{max}$ is.

Comment: I know the constants (provided in the paper) and I know enough math to manipulate the equation in the provided form. This answer does not answer my question at all.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I think $γ(R)$ can be measured by the scattering of the silver nanoparticles. I don't know how to find $γ(R)$ from  $λ_{max}$